# Fatal error detected: Module object for pyimod02_importers is NULL

Tags: python, fatal-error, unhandled-exception, auto-py-to-exe

After compiling the python script with auto-py-to-exe, I'm getting this error when I try to open the exe file. There's literally no information about this error on the internet, any ideas?

[image]

[image]

List of the modules I use in the script:

```
import secrets
import string
import tkinter as tk

import customtkinter
import pyperclip
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is python 3.11.4. Downgrade to 3.11.3 for now. Tested using two windows machines one running 3.11.4 and one 3.11.3.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I had the same issue with `pyinstaller` in a conda environment, by default it's python 3.11.4. I downgraded to 3.11.3 and the problem is gone.

Comment: Can you please mention which pyinstaller version did you have ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case, it was my auto-py-to-exe version.

I upgraded my auto-py-to-exe version, and this error was fixed:

> pip install --upgrade auto-py-to-exe

Answer (score -1):

I am going to explain how I solved this same error, I also used customtkinter, first you must locate yourself in the folder where you have your files and scripts, you are going to create a virtual environment, for this you go to the file explorer path and write cmd and das Before, the terminal opens in that path, or you simply right click on a space in the folder that you have open and click: "open terminal", in this terminal you will create the virtual environment and activate it like this
step 1: pip install virtualenv
step 2: virtualenv env
step 3: cd env
step 4: cd scripts
step 5: activate.bat
After activating it, we are going to check that we have all the necessary files, for this we check the path with the following command
step 6: dir
check that all your necessary files are there for your script to run
then we are going to install pyinstaller like this
step 7: pip install pyinstaller
then we check that our libraries and necessary packages are installed in this virtual environment, for that we type the command:
step 8: pip freeze
customtkinter does not come by default, we must install it like this
step 9: pip install customtkinter
NOTE: if you have any other library or package external to Python, you must install it in the same way pip install (library name)
then, with pip freeze, you check again that all the libraries are already added
lastly, install and run auto-py-to-exe like so
step 10: pip install auto-py-to-exe
step 11: auto-py-to-exe

auto-py will open, the rest is simple add the .py file, choose "a directory", add "additional files", add the customtkinter path manually like so
C:/Users/(USERNAME)/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Lib/site-packages/customtkinter
en USERNAME va tu usuario de la Windows
then in the advanced options part, go to "--hidden-import" press + and then write csutomtkinter (this is to complement the path we entered earlier, since the customtkinter module, being relatively new, is under development and there are still errors)
perfect now you click on generate .exe and ready you wait, you will know the rest, look for your file in the:
carpeta ./dist/(nombre de tu carpeta)/(nombre de tu archivo)/.exe